# How to know most used procedure in my database?

Tags: sql-server

I completed my project, there are many procedures used and now I got the job to find the mostly used procedure and there average execution time.

In this way I know what are the procedures I need to tune first?

It there any way to get procedure execution history for a particular database?

Comment: sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use the sys.dm_exec_query_stats dynamic management view.  There are two columns in this view called execution_count, and total_worker_time that will help you.

execution_count gives the total number of times the stored procedure in question was executed since the last time it was recompiled.

total_worker_time gives the total CPU time in milliseconds that was spent executing this stored procedure since the last time it was recompiled.

Here is an MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx

Comment: It's pretty hard to associate a row in dm_exec_query_stats with a stored procedure.  Not sure how useful this is without the link.

Comment: @Andomar If 2008+ `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dm_exec_cached_plans` to look for the stored procedures that have been compiled into query plans.  The function `dm_exec_query_plan` can be used to retrieve the `object id` for a plan, which in turn can be translated into the procedure's name:

```
select  object_name(qp.objectid)
,       cp.usecounts
from    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
cross apply
        sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) qp
where   cp.objtype = 'Proc'
order by
        cp.usecounts desc
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to check [***SQL Server Profiler***](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/) for this.
You can check the details in MSDN and other places as well.

But, before using it in production server, you need to keep in mind that:
 `Profiler adds too much overhead to production server`. So, first check when your site has less no of hits, and go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

This is what the [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is for. With it you can keep track of query run count, execution time, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not easy to use profiler to get average execution time for last 5 day of execution of procedures

Comment: I understand. For that particular case, Michael's answer should be  helpful. If your goal is to do a lot of tuning though, the profiler is great for identifying what's slow and why.